# Railsアプリの消費税の小数点を四捨五入するやり方について教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

viewには品名、数量、単価があります。
数量が「1」、単価が「485,560」の場合は消費税額が「38,844.8 -> 38,845」
数量が「-1」、単価が「485,560」の場合は消費税額が「38,844.8 -> 38,844」
になり、消費税額が異なる金額になってしまいます。
消費税額を四捨五入の「38,845」にしたいのですが、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？
ご教示の程、宜しくお願い申し上げます。

```
<p class="pill-left total_fee_wrapper_02"><span class="total_fee_background tax_border_left total_fee_font_size_02">消費税額</span>¥<span class="total_fee total_fee_font_size"><%= number_with_delimiter((BigDecimal(@selling_price_total_07.to_i + @selling_price_total_15.to_i + @selling_price_total_37.to_i + @selling_price_total_52.to_i) * BigDecimal(@tax)).ceil) %></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

すみません、「ceil」メソッドを「round」メソッドに変更したら、四捨五入することができました。

参考サイト
https://www.rubylife.jp/ini/numeric_class/index3.html